# Cakephp - How to construct custom URLs from a drop down select input?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to use a  drop down input in my cakephp application, with this I want the drop down on submit to render the url like so:

```
www.example.com/cake/FILE/VALUE
```

However the only url i can get the select input to create is the following:

```
www.example.com/cake/FILE?form_value=VALUE
```

How do I go about making the URL SEO friendly like the first example without using httaccess because I want the URL to appear seo friendly in the search engines eyes.

Here is the code I am using.

In The VIEW

```
echo $form->input('form_value', array(
         'label'  => '',
         'type'  => 'select',
         'options' => $listOfOptions,
          'selected'  => '0',));
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, get the value of "form_value" through `$file = $this->data['FILE']['form_value']` and do a redirect `$this->redirect(array('action' => 'download', $file))`.

You then create a function called download which should look like this:

```
<?php
function download($file = null) {
    if ($file != null) {
        /*make download*/
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('no file specified')
    }
?>
```

If you don't want the action "download" to appear in the URL you can use Cakes built-in routes in cakephp/app/config/routes.php.

With something like this you could map the index-action to the download-action:
    Router::connect('/FILE/*', array('controller' => 'files', 'action' => 'download'));
See http://book.cakephp.org/view/46/Routes-Configuration for better explanation.

Comment: Ill try your method, its not exactly what i was asking but ill have to try something, also i shouldnt have used the word FILE, what i meant was CONTROLLER. e.g. cake/controller/neptune instead of  cake/controller?planet_name=neptune